# Google App Engine with Django Patch and the Deferred library

Tags: django, google-app-engine, app-engine-patch

Anyone successfully using deferred.defer library with app-engine-patch?

If so please share.

Comment: Are you having a specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work after getting a tip on the [app-engine-patch news group](http://groups.google.com/group/app-engine-patch/browse_thread/thread/847a2f9819c056c4):

> I used a different approach to get the
>   same effect.  I placed all my deferred
>   tasks into a separate module.  In the
>   module's imports, I included the
>   import:
>
> import common.appenginepatch.main
>
> This causes all AEP initialization to
>   occur.  Deferred is working like a
>   champ in production.
>
> johnP

Thanks JohnP!